# How can I calculate the npv ( net present value) with different rates?

Tags: r

I have two vectors

```
CF <- c ( 500,500,200)
rates <- c( 0.1, 0.15 , 0.2)
```

the vectors can vary in length and in values, the equation would be:

```
NVP = (CF1*(1+R1)^-1) + (CF2*(1+R2)^-1*(1+R1)^-1) + (CF3*(1+R3)^-1*(1+R2)^-1*(1+R1)^-1)
```

I have tried this:

```
for(n in 1:length(CF)) 
{
  if ( length(R)==1)
  {
  van <- van + CFFC[n] * ((1 + R) ^ -n)
  }
  else
  {
    aux [n] <- CF[n]* ((1+ R[c(1:n)])^ -1) 
  }  
}
```

Please help, this is my first time programming

Comment: Hi @Viera Eterovic, you also need to show your desired result (`NVP=?`) for us to check the rightness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NPV` can be seen as the dot product of two vectors `CF` and `cumprod( (1+rates)^(-1) )`, where `cumprod( (1+rates)^(-1) )` is the cumulative products of `(1+rates)^(-1)`, i.e.,
`( (1 + R1)^(-1), (1 + R2)^(-1) * (1 + R1)^(-1), (1 + R3)^(-1) * (1 + R2)^(-1) * (1 + R1)^(-1) )`.

```
CF * cumprod( (1+rates)^(-1) )
# 454.5455 395.2569 131.7523
```